# Place of Android app launch

Tags: android, launch

Is it possible to track on Android from where somebody has started an application (i.e. from the drawer, from recent apps menu, or from desktop shortcuts, etc.)?

Comment: interesting question. the information will be useful for user behavior analysis. but i think the answer is : you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this isn't possible.

Even if it was, consider how easily such functionality could be abused by **malicious software**. You can listen to intents directed at you, and those that are broadcast, but application launching should not be a broadcast event.

What you may be able to do is [replace the launcher](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bc1bfa440da23e22). If the user agrees to it.

You might also be able to hack a work-around by reading the logcat logs. For instance, give your application the `android.permission.READ_LOGS` permission and parse the logs to determine the application that launched it. This is just an idea, however... it sounds like something you wouldn't want to rely on.

Comment: Be wary of the logs. Even if you get it working that way, it won't work the same on every device (not all of them have the same log messages)

Comment: True. I certainly wouldn't write an app that relied on them... let's put it that way :P

Answer (score 1):

If you built your own home screen it could give you some of that information.

But on a stock device with any available home screens no probably not.